# Knockout.js - Filtering a computed with multiple conditions

Tags: knockout.js

Trying to filter a computed with multiple conditions.  I have seen lots of examples where the return statement is nested with multiple conditions, but I truly dont understand why they work.  My example here might not be a candidate for a nested return statements but I'm not sure how to execute this.

```
//ko.utils.arrayFilter - filter the items using the filter text
viewModel.filteredItems = ko.computed(function() {
    var filter = this.filter().toLowerCase();
    if (!filter) {
        return this.items();
    } else {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.items(), function(item) {
            return (item.fullName().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1);
        });
    }

    //*** THIS LOGIC WORKS BY ITSELF BUT NOT COMBINED WITH THE ABOVE LOGIC ***
    //var t = this.selectedTag();
    //if (t == "all") return this.items();
    //return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.items(), function(item) {
    //    return item.tag == t;
    //});

}, viewModel);
```

Here is the full example in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/boyus/qTb5Q/12/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the logic in your computed was slightly incorrect and you were not setting the selected tags correctly in the data-bind's.

Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/qTb5Q/14/ for a working solution.

Here is the altered computed function:

```
  viewModel.filteredItems = ko.computed(function() {
      var filter = this.filter().toLowerCase();
      if (!filter) {
        var t = this.selectedTag().toLowerCase();
        if (!t || t == "all") return this.items();
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.items(), function(item) {
            return item.tag().toLowerCase() == t;
        });
      } else {
          return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.items(), function(item) {
              return (item.fullName().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1);
          });
      }
  }, viewModel);
```

Comment: This partially works but fails to allow the secondary search to perform anything if there is a value in the primary search's input box.  This is VERY close though. I tried changing the first observable on the fly and tried changing the input box with some simple jQuery code when one of the tags were chosen but to no success.

Comment: Ah, I get what you are trying to achieve, now. Here is an amended solution that does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/qTb5Q/18/

Comment: This is much closer. I really wanted them to be mutually exclusive options but I think I can figure that out from here. Thanks.

Comment: If anyone searches for this later and found this example like their own code, here is my "completed" code: http://jsfiddle.net/boyus/qTb5Q/27/

I'm sure there is a MUCH more efficient way to write this code, but my brain couldn't find it.